# Load content with AJAX and Fancybox 1.3

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

All,
I'm trying to load some content into a fancybox. I'd like to load some page content using AJAX. How can I load this content into my fancybox using AJAX and version 1.3?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of fancybox are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To load AJAX content into FancyBox by clicking a link, you could use the following method, taken directly from the FancyBox examples ([http://fancybox.net/howto](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)):

```
<a class="various" href="/demo/ajax.php">Ajax</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox();
});
```

Note this works perfectly but if you want to specify other parameters to the fancy box you can do following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        hideOnOverlayClick:false,
        hideOnContentClick:false,
        ....,
    });
});
```

For other parameters refer to the fancybox documentation.

You could always specify the `href` within the JavaScript by using the `href` option (http://fancybox.net/api).

**UPDATE:** I see you're using 1.3.4 so links have been updated accordingly.

**UPDATE:** If you were to update to FancyBox 2, you could use the following example from the FancyBox website (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples):

```
<a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="/demo/ajax.php">Ajax</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

Comment: Was your example using 2.0? If so I can upgrade to that because that example was perfect.

Comment: My original example was using FancyBox 2 which can be found at: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Comment: Thanks I've upgrade this and it loads it how I want except the black overlay is actually on top of the page content. Any reason why that would be? If I display a picture with it though, it loads the image on top of the overlay.

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue could be there, could you have any existing CSS that would be overriding the FancyBox styles? Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: I got it figure out. Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 1):

Just taken from http://fancybox.net/ which use 1.3

```
$("#Link").fancybox({
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
        data    : 'mydata=test'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test_function(){

     $.fancybox({
        'scrolling'         : 'no',
        'padding'           : 0,
        'centerOnScroll'    : true,
        'href'              : 'faq.php',
        'type'              : 'ajax'
     });
}
```